# How to insert text into a conf file?

Tags: linux, text-processing

In `nginx.conf` I have:

```
server {
  listen 81;
  ...snip...
}
```

I want the file to look like this:

```
server {
  listen 81;
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  ...snip...
}
```

So the text (`if..`) should only be inserted if it does not already exist.

Is this possible to do using some in-built program at the command line?

Something like:

- Open a file
- See if it has certain text in it
- If it does not then locate certain text (`listen 81;`) and on the next line after it insert a few lines of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), wrapped up in a shell script.  Completely untested; invoke as "./script /path/to/nginx.conf"; note that it does *not* look for the complete text you wanted to add, only a hopefully-sufficiently-long token from its first line.

```
#! /bin/sh

if grep -q "document_root/system/maintenance" "$1"
then :
else
     set -e
     sed < "$1" > "$1.tmp" \
     '/listen 81;/a\
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {\
    return 503;\
  }
  '
     mv -f "$1.tmp" "$1"
fi
```